# Erro Conexão Banco de dados; "relation does not exist"

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Estou com Problema para Salvar Dados de uma tela para o meu banco de dados estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

> "org.postgresql.util.PSQL.Exception: ERROR: column "nome" of relation "cadastroproduto" does not existe posição: 29"

a posição 29 e a seguinte:

```
pst = conex.com.prepareStatement("insert into cadastroproduto(nome, Preco_De_Custo,Preco_De_Venda,Marca,Categoria,Origem,Unidade_Medida) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
```

O Código que estou usando para o controle que esta dando erro e o Seguinte:

```
package controle;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import modelo.ModeloCadastroProduto;

public class ControleCadastroProduto {
ConexaoBD conex = new ConexaoBD();
ModeloCadastroProduto mod;

public class ControleCadastroProduto {
    ConexaoBD conex = new ConexaoBD();
    ModeloCadastroProduto mod;

    public ControleCadastroProduto() {
        this.mod = new ModeloCadastroProduto();
    }

    public void Salvar(ModeloCadastroProduto mod){
        conex.conexao();
        try {
            PreparedStatement pst;
            pst = conex.com.prepareStatement("insert into cadastroproduto(nome, Preco_De_Custo,Preco_De_Venda,Marca,Categoria,Origem,Unidade_Medida) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            pst.setString(1,mod.getNome());
            pst.setDouble(2,mod.getPrecodecusto());
            pst.setDouble(3,mod.getPrecodevenda());
            pst.setString(4,mod.getMarca());
            pst.setString(5,mod.getCategoria());
            pst.setString(6,mod.getOrigem());
            pst.setString(7,mod.getUnidademedida());
            pst.execute();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Dados Cadastrados com Sucesso!");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Erro Ao Cadastrar\nErro: "+ex);
        }

        conex.desconecta();
    }
}
```

Código da tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE public.cadastroproduto
(
    "ID_Produto" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"CadastroProduto_ID_Produto_seq"'::regclass),
    "Nome" character(1) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "Preco_De_Custo" money NOT NULL,
    "Preco_De_Venda" money,
    "Marca" character varying(60) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "Categoria" character varying(60) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "Origem" character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "Unidade_Medida" character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT "CadastroProduto_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("ID_Produto")
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.cadastroproduto
    OWNER to postgres;
```

Comment: você verificou se o nome da coluna `nome` esta exatamente assim na tabela `cadastroproduto` no seu banco?

Comment: esta exatamente igual.

Comment: Na dúvida coloca na pergunta a estrutura da tabela

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> column "nome" of relation "cadastroproduto"

Nomes de identificadores (tabelas, campo etc) com letras maiúsculas ou caracteres especiais no PostgreSQL devem ser delimitados com aspas, caso contrário não serão reconhecidos.

Mude:

```
insert into cadastroproduto(nome, Preco_De_Custo)
```

Para: aplique isso para todos os campos que tem letras maiúsculas.

```
pst = conex.com.prepareStatement("insert into cadastroproduto(nome, \"Preco_De_Custo\", \"Preco_De_Venda\", \"Marca\", \"Categoria\", \"Origem\",\"Unidade_Medida\")
```

Se possível é melhor mudar os nomes das colunas e deixar tudo em caixa baixa, assim evita-se os escape.

Comment: mesmo com as aspas o erro ainda persiste.

Comment: @matheusferreira coloca na pergunta o create da tabela, no pgAdmin também acontece esse erro?

Comment: já coloquei a create , não somente quando vou salvar algo, preencho os campos e clico no botão salvar ele executa a validação com a conexão do banco de dados e logo depois de clicar ok ele apresenta o erro que especifiquei no começo.

Comment: graças a sua resposta eu consegui solucionar o problema, bom fiz alteração no pgadmin das letras maiusculas e os caracteres e deu certo, muito obrigado.